# Cursor and CSV using utl_file package

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, export-to-csv, utl-file

Hi I want to create a csv file using plsql utl file. For that I am creating cursor in utl file but I dont want to enter duplicate data. Because I want to create that csv file daily from the same table. Please help

I tried by cursor but I have no idea how to restrict duplicate entries because I want to create the csv file from same table on daily basis

Comment: If the volume of data is very low (tens of thousands of records or less), and if your DBA is okay with the security implications of dumping files to the local database server, utl_file can work for you. For larger volume and freedom to pull the file to anywhere, consider using sqlplus and the "set markup csv on" plus spool. And if your data is massive (tens of millions of rows), consider writing a program in Python or something similar to pull out the data and write it to a file. utl_file is by far the slowest method of all.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor selects data; it is its `where` clause that filters which data it'll return.

Therefore, set it so that it fetches only rows you're interested in. For example, one option is to use a *timestamp* column which tells when was that particular row inserted into the table. Cursor would then

```
select ...
from that_table
where timestamp_column >= trunc(sysdate)
```

to select data created *today*. It is up to you to set it to any other value you want.